# Django get yesterdays login count

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a view where I am fetching some analytical data about login information as follows:

```
def get_analytics(request):

    total_users = User.objects.all().count()
    # Number of users who dogged in once to our system today
    today_login_count= User.objects.filter(last_login__startswith=timezone.now().date()).count()

    #Number of users who dogged in once to our system in the last week
    today = timezone.now().date() + timezone.timedelta(days=1)
    last_week = timezone.now().date() - timezone.timedelta(days=7)
    last_month = timezone.now().date() - timezone.timedelta(days=30)
    week_login_count = User.objects.filter(last_login__range=(last_week, today)).count()

    #Number of users who dogged in once to our system in the last month
    month_login_count = User.objects.filter(last_login__range=(last_month, today)).count()

    data = {}
    data['total_users'] = total_users
    data['today_login_count'] = today_login_count
    data['week_login_count'] = week_login_count
    data['month_login_count'] = month_login_count

    return JSONResponse(data)
```

I want to get the total number of users who did login **only** yesterday. How can I query it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User.objects.filter(
    last_login__date=timezone.now().date() - timedelta(days=1)
).count()
```

Comment: I thought of the same, but doesn't it give total number of users who logged in in past two days i.e. today and yesterday?

Comment: @Nitish No, it doesn't. It will give that if `filter` argument is `last_login__date__gte=...`.

Comment: I just had to update it to `User.objects.filter(last_login__startswith=timezone.now().date() - timezone.timedelta(days=1)).count()`